# What is the ObjectFactory role during JAXB-Unmarshalling?

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling, objectfactory

I'm using JAXB 2.2.2 to parse a simple XML-REST stream. This is the piece of code:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( "com.example.entities" );
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
r = (Response )u.unmarshal( inputStream );
```

ObjectFactory class:

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    public Response createRsp() {
        return new Response();
    }
}
```

Response class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="rsp")
@XmlType
public class Response { ... }
```

The "com.example.entities" must contain the ObjectFactory class or jaxb.index. I would like to use the ObjectFactory class in order to decide some pojo initialization, but these class is never used: the Response class is always instantiated by class.newInstance() directly.
Is there something wrong in this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can leverage the [`@XmlType`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlType.html) annotation to control how the objects are created:

```
@XmlType(factoryClass=ObjectFactory.class, factoryMethod="createRsp")
public class Response {
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-factory-methods.html

Comment: My goodness, I spent the last several hours looking in vain for clues as to how to get my factory method to work, until I read this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The ObjectFactory class generated by the XJC compiler is not useful to the factoryClass and factoryMethod @XmlType annotation because the factoryMethod must be a static no-arg method and the XJC generate instance methods.