# Why is the ObjectFactory not used during unmarshalling?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have defined the following `ObjectFactory`:

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    public Dogs createDogs() {
        return new Dogs();
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(name = "dog")
    public Dog createDog(DogType value) {
        return new Dog(value);
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(name = "fido", substitutionHeadName = "dog", substitutionHeadNamespace = "")
    public Dog createFido(DogType value) {
        return new Dog("fido", value);
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(name = "barks", substitutionHeadName = "dog", substitutionHeadNamespace = "")
    public Dog createBarks(DogType value) {
        return new Dog("barks", value);
    }
}
```

(`Dogs` class is trivial, `Dog` and `DogType` see below or [here](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/tree/master/runtime/src/test/java/org/hisrc/xml/bind/tests/dogs).)

I am unmarshalling the following XML:

```
<listOfDogs>
    <dogs>
        <dog>
            <name>henry</name>
            <sound>bark</sound>
        </dog>
        <fido>
            <sound>woof</sound>
        </fido>
        <barks>
            <sound>miau</sound>
        </barks>
    </dogs>
</listOfDogs>
```

I was sincerely expecting that JAXB will call my `createFido(...)` and `createBarks(...)` methods during unmarshalling. But this does not happen. The `Dog` constructor is invoked directly via reflection, the appropriate `create...` methods are not used.

My question is:

**Why is `ObjectFactory` not called during unmarshalling?**

Shouldn't it be? Or is ist just a dummy to hold the `@XmlRegistry`/`@XmlElementDecl` declarations?

I have also checked this question:

[What is the ObjectFactory role during JAXB-Unmarshalling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780184/what-is-the-objectfactory-role-during-jaxb-unmarshalling)

The solution there is to use `@XmlType.factoryClass` and `factoryMethod`. This will not work here because I don't want to statically link my `DogType` to the certain instantiation routine. I want it to be decided in the runtime based on the element name. My goal is to instantiate the same class but differently, depending on the element name.

---

Now some code to make it complete.

Root element class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "listOfDogs")
public class Dogs {

    private List<JAXBElement<DogType>> dogs = new LinkedList<JAXBElement<DogType>>();

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "dogs")
    @XmlElementRef(name = "dog")
    public List<JAXBElement<DogType>> getDogs() {
        return this.dogs;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Dogs [dogs=" + dogs + "]";
    }
}
```

`Dog`, the wrapper element class for the `DogType`:

```
public class Dog extends JAXBElement<DogType> {

    public static final QName NAME = new QName("dog");

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Dog(DogType value) {
        super(NAME, DogType.class, value);
    }

    public Dog(String dogName, DogType value) {
        super(NAME, DogType.class, value);
    }

    @Override
    public QName getName() {
        final DogType value = getValue();
        if (value != null && value.getName() != null) {
            return new QName(value.getName());
        } else {
            return super.getName();
        }
    }
}
```

`DogType`:

```
public class DogType {

    private String name;
    private String sound;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String dogName) {
        this.name = dogName;
    }

    public String getSound() {
        return sound;
    }

    public void setSound(String sound) {
        this.sound = sound;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
public class DogTest {

    @Test
    public void unmarshallsDogs() throws JAXBException {
        final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
                .newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
        final Dogs dogs = (Dogs) context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(
                getClass().getResource("dogs.xml"));
        Assert.assertEquals(3, dogs.getDogs().size());
        // Does not work
//      Assert.assertEquals("henry", dogs.getDogs().get(0).getValue()
//              .getName());
        Assert.assertEquals("bark", dogs.getDogs().get(0).getValue().getSound());
        // Does not work
//      Assert.assertEquals("fido", dogs.getDogs().get(1).getValue()
//              .getName());
        Assert.assertEquals("woof", dogs.getDogs().get(1).getValue().getSound());
        // Does not work
//      Assert.assertEquals("barks", dogs.getDogs().get(2).getValue()
//              .getName());
        Assert.assertEquals("miau", dogs.getDogs().get(2).getValue().getSound());
    }
}
```

The code is also available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/tree/master/runtime/src/test/java/org/hisrc/xml/bind/tests/dogs) and [here](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/tree/master/runtime/src/test/resources/org/hisrc/xml/bind/tests/dogs).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer is because the factory methods are not generated into the `@XmlType` annotation to tell JAXB to do so:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "listOfDogs")
@XmlType(factoryClass=ObjectFactory.class, factoryMethod="createDogs") // not generated
public class Dogs {
```

---

> Shouldn't it be? Or is ist just a dummy to hold the
>   @XmlRegistry/@XmlElementDecl declarations?

In my opinion yes it should be used to instantiate the classes.

`ObjectFactory` is a throw back to JAXB 1.0.  In JAXB 1.0 the spec defined what the generated interfaces looked like and implementations could back those generated interfaces with what ever impl they wanted to provide.  Back then you needed to use the `ObjectFactory` class to create your model in a vendor independent way.

JAXB 2.0 switched to a POJO model where you were free to use the default constructor.  If JAXB 1.0 had never existed would there be an `ObjectFactory` class, that's hard to tell.  Since it previously existed the `ObjectFactory` class was kept for a couple of reasons:

1. It made it easier for people transitioning for people transitioning from JAXB 1.0 to interact with the generated model.
2. It provided a location to specify the multiple root elements for a class via `@XmlElementDecl`.  The `@XmlRegistry` annotation is really just a marker annotation used to indicate the class that contains the `@XmlElementDecl` annotations without restricting it to a class called `ObjectFactory`.

---

### Your Use Case

Your use case may be able to be achieved with an `XmlAdapter`, although its not clear to me what logic you are trying to have in the `ObjectFactory`.

**XmlAdapter (DogAdapter)**

Your custom logic goes on the `XmlAdapter`.

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.*;

public class DogAdapter extends XmlAdapter<JAXBElement<DogType>, JAXBElement<DogType>> {

    @Override
    public JAXBElement<DogType> unmarshal(JAXBElement<DogType> v) throws Exception {
        return new Dog(v.getName().getLocalPart(), v.getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public JAXBElement<DogType> marshal(JAXBElement<DogType> v) throws Exception {
        return v;
    }

}
```

**Dogs**

The `XmlAdapter` is referenced from the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement(name = "listOfDogs")
public class Dogs {

    private List<JAXBElement<DogType>> dogs = new LinkedList<JAXBElement<DogType>>();

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "dogs")
    @XmlElementRef(name = "dog")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DogAdapter.class)
    public List<JAXBElement<DogType>> getDogs() {
        return this.dogs;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Dogs [dogs=" + dogs + "]";
    }

}
```

**ObjectFactory**

`ObjectFactory` is now a dumb class that just holds the `@XmlElementDecl` annotations:

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    public Dogs createDogs() {
        return new Dogs();
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(name = "dog")
    public JAXBElement<DogType> createDog(DogType value) {
        return new Dog(value);
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(name = "fido", substitutionHeadName = "dog", substitutionHeadNamespace = "")
    public JAXBElement<DogType> createFido(DogType value) {
        return new JAXBElement<DogType>(new QName("fido"), DogType.class, value);
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(name = "barks", substitutionHeadName = "dog", substitutionHeadNamespace = "")
    public JAXBElement<DogType> createBarks(DogType value) {
        return new JAXBElement<DogType>(new QName("barks"), DogType.class, value);
    }

}
```

---

### UPDATE

> My question, however is more about the specification. According to the
>   spec, should the create* methods from the ObjectFactory be executed or
>   not?

In JAXB 2 there is no difference in a model created from scratch versus one generated from an XML Schema.  As such you need to look to the spec at what it says about classes.  According to what is reference below it comes down to no-arg constructor or a specified factory method.

From section ***8.7.1.2 Mapping*** of the [JAXB 2.2 (JSR-222)](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) specification:

> a class must have a public or protected no-arg constructor or a
>   factory method identified by {factoryClass(), factoryMethod()} unless
>   it is adapted using @XmlJavaTypeAdapter.

Comment: So `ObjectFactory` is just a dummy to hold `@XmlRegistry`/`@XmlElementDecl` declarations? Does not feel correct to me.

Comment: @lexicore - I'm expanding my answer to explain more, but it may take some time.

Comment: @lexicore - What logic are you trying to get in your `ObjectFactory` class?

Comment: Passing different parameters to the instance constructor depending on the root element name. Please check `createDog`, `createFido` and `createBarks` methods in my example. They create the same instance but pass different names to the constructor.

Comment: This is also why I can't use `@XmlType` with `factoryClass` and `factoryMethod` - I use want to use the same class for differen root elements.

Comment: @lexicore - I've added an `XmlAdapter` example that should give you equivalent behaviour to what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your effort Blaise. My question, however is more about the specification. According to the spec, should the `create*` methods from the `ObjectFactory` be executed or not? If they should then there's a bug in JAXB RI. If not, you have provided a very good workaround. So, practically the problem is solved, but I'm also interested to understand the specification.

Comment: @lexicore - The spec says default constructor or specified factory method (see update).

Comment: Sorry, forgot to award the bounty.