# Jaxb unmarshal as a singleton?

Tags: java, jaxb

I have an application that loads some parameters from an xml file:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyParams.class);
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
MyParams obj = (MyParams) u.unmarshal(inputStream);
```

I would like to make MyParams Singleton, is it possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above answer on using @XmlType with a factory class and method is correct. It is rare, but there are situations where a singleton makes sense in XML.

I have a case where I want to marshall/unmarshall values, such as dates, strings, integers, etc. One of the value types is null. In my hierachy, a Java null reference means unspecified, so I want an explicit Null class to mean a value that is specified to be null.

Naturally, there is no reason to have more than once instance of Null, so it is a singleton. I put the factory class inside Null, as follows:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "null")
@XmlType(factoryClass = Null.Factory.class, factoryMethod = "nullInstance")
public final class Null extends Value {
  public static class Factory {
    public static Null nullInstance(
    ) {
      return INSTANCE;
    }
  }

  public static final Null INSTANCE = new Null();

  // Construct

  /**
   * Construct
   */
  private Null(
  ) {
    if (INSTANCE != null) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Null is a singleton class");
    }
  }

  // Object

  @Override
  public String toString(
  ) {
    return getClass().getSimpleName();
  }

  // Value

  @Override
  public boolean isCompound(
  ) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isScalar(
  ) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you probably can override JAXB's instantiation mechanism somehow to reuse an existing instance (your singleton) instead of creating a new instance.

As a side not, I thought this should work with `ObjectFactory` but it did not for me:

> [Why is the ObjectFactory not used during unmarshalling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26439184/why-is-the-objectfactory-not-used-during-unmarshalling)

But from my pont of view this would be not the best design. In this case any unmarshalling of the `MyParams` will go into the same instance.

My suggestion would be to unmarshal into a distinct instance first and then merge these unmarshalled params into your singleton. Singleton per se is often an anti-pattern, but marrying it with JAXB unmarshalling would take the potential "anti-" even further.

**Update**

Seems like you can use [`@XmlType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlType.html) annotation with [`factoryClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlType.html#factoryClass()) and [`factoryMethod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlType.html#factoryMethod()) to specify how the instances of `MyParams` should be created.

So probably something like:

```
@XmlType(factoryClass=MyParamsFactory.class, factoryMethod="createMyParams")
public class MyParams {
    ...

    public static MyParams getInstance() { ... }
}

public class MyParamsFactory {
    public MyParams createMyParams() { return MyParams.getInstance(); }
}
```

should work.

**However, as I said, I think it is not a good idea to unmarshal to singleton.** This is an explicit warning.

Comment: `createMyParams` should be static as specified for factoryClass in http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlType.html